# MeteorJS wrapasync not working inside iron router

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I want to check whether user has achieved some level and do the routing according to that. But this does not wait for the wrapasync return. How to achieve this?

Router.js

```
var getLevelAsync = function (userID, callback) {
    Meteor.call('getLevel', Meteor.userId(), function (err, data) {
        callback(null, data['level']);
    })
}

var getLevel = Meteor.wrapAsync(getLevelAsync);


Router.route('/verifyData', function(){
    var level = getLevel(Meteor.userId());
    if(level < 3) this.render('somepage');
    else this.render('another page');

})
```

server/methods.js

```
getLevel: function (userID) {
        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userID});
    }
```

Comment: WrapAsync does not work on the client. You can use a callback, a promise or a reactive computation, but not the pseudo-synchronous behavior provided by `wrapAsync`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Meteor.wrapAsync on the client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478707/how-to-use-meteor-wrapasync-on-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.wrapAsync` wraps a future around a function, which can only be done on the server. You do not need a Meteor method to achieve what you are trying to do, either, you can simply render the same page but render different contexts based on the current user.

```
{{#with currentUser}}
  {{#if aboveLevelThree}}
    <h1>Congrats! You're in the special club!</h1>
  {{else}}
    <h3>Sorry mate, get a better score to advance</h3>
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Where your template helpers are like this:

```
Template['someTemplate'].helpers({
  aboveLevelThree: function () {
    return this.level > 3;
  }
});
```