# Usage of asynchronous validation within an allow hook

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, easypost

I am trying to validate on an allow hook in Meteor. The following is what I do.

```
let EasyPost = Npm.require('node-easypost')(process.env.EASYPOST_KEY);

Addresses.allow({
  insert(userId, document) {
    check(document, Addresses.simpleSchema());
    EasyPost.createAndVerify(document, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        // insert should not be allowed.
      } else {
        document = Object.assign(document, {
          easypost: result
        })
      }
    })
  }
});
```

However, I can't use `return false` because it is an asynchronous operation. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use promises? Which function is async?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wrapAsync](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) method as explained [here](http://www.smashingthingstogether.com/the-javascript-runtime-fibers-and-meteor-wrapasync/) or [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058205/meteor-wrapasync-syntax). I never actually used it in `allow` sections, because I prefer to use methods, but it should work, but if it's not, you can always switch to methods, and use it there.